# Change MenuItem caption at runtime

Tags: user-interface, mfc, menu, menuitem, visual-studio-2003

I have a Menu with all sorts of Menu items, as you normally would. Every MenuItem (button) has a caption and I'd like to change that caption at runtime. On a normal button that isn't really a problem, I just call `GetDlgItem(ID)->SetWindowText(CString);`

However I can't do that on the menu items since I can't assign ID's to any of them. The ID field in the Properties editor actually says "ID can not be edited".

So how do I change the menu items text at runtime?

**EDIT**: I have tried using the CMenu::ModifyMenu however I have been unsuccessful. I don't know how to specify the button (element) to change. Also, I have doubts in the correctness of the way I pass the CString as an argument.

This is my (failed) attempt:

```
CString str = "Foo";
CMenu * pMenu = m_wndToolBar.GetMenu();
pMenu->ModifyMenu(1, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, 0 /*Don't know what to pass as nIDNewItem */, str);
```

This (the call to the ModifyMenu method) throws a debug assertion error. Please not that I don't know what nIDNewItem.

Answer (score 7):

You could try adding an `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` handler for the menu option, and calling `pCmdUI->SetText()` in it.

Answer (score 7):

You should get menu item's command id first. Try this:

```
tr = L"Foo";
CMenu * pMenu = m_wndToolBar.GetMenu();
MENUITEMINFO info;
info.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
info.fMask = MIIM_ID;
VERIFY(pMenu->GetMenuItemInfo(1, &info, TRUE));
pMenu->ModifyMenuW(info.wID, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_STRING, info.wID, tr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Menus are not windows, they are menus. You cannot use `GetDlgItem` to access a menu.

In MFC, `CMenu` class can be used to create and/or control menus. [`CMenu::ModifyMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tbfebs6%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) might be the thing you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have stumbled upon CMenu::ModifyMenu before, however I didn't succeed in changing the caption. Please see my edited question! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the call to `GetMenu` is returning a valid CMenu? Try calling only `GetMenu()` instead of `m_wndToolBar.GetMenu()`.

Your call to `ModifyMenu` seems to be right, if you pass a `MF_BYPOSITION` you do not need the 3rd parameter. Also note that the 1st parameter (position) starts at 0.